# A Pivot table in r with binary output

Tags: r

I have the following dataset

```
#datset

id  attributes  value
1   a,b,c        1
2   c,d          0
3   b,e          1
```

I wish to make a pivot table out of them and assign binary values to the attribute (1 to the attributes if they exist otherwise assign 0 to them). My ideal output will be the following:

```
#output

id  a   b   c   d   e   Value
1   1   1   1   0   0   1
2   0   0   1   1   0   0
3   0   1   0   0   1   1
```

Any tip is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We split the 'attributes' column by ',', get the frequency with `mtabulate` from `qdapTools` and `cbind` with the first and third column.

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df1[1], mtabulate(strsplit(df1$attributes, ",")), df1[3])
#  id a b c d e value
#1  1 1 1 1 0 0     1
#2  2 0 0 1 1 0     0
#3  3 0 1 0 0 1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R:

```
attributes <- sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$attributes), split=','))))
cols <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(0, nrow(df)*length(attributes)), ncol=length(attributes)))
names(cols) <- attributes
df <- cbind.data.frame(df, cols)
df <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x){attributes <- strsplit(x['attributes'], split=','); x[unlist(attributes)] <- 1;x})))[c('id', attributes, 'value')]
df
  id a b c d e value
1  1 1 1 1 0 0     1
2  2 0 0 1 1 0     0
3  3 0 1 0 0 1     1
```